# Solana Golang (gagliardetto/solana-go): how to create privateKeyGetter?

Tags: transactions, sign

```
tx1, err := solana.TransactionFromDecoder(bin.NewBinDecoder(txByte))
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("transaction decoding failed: %w", err)
}

pvString := ""
privateKey, err := solana.PrivateKeyFromBase58(pvString)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse private key: %w", err)
}

sign, err := tx1.Sign()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

opts := rpc.TransactionOpts{SkipPreflight: true}


client := rpc.New(rpc.MainNetBeta_RPC)

sig, err := client.SendRawTransactionWithOpts(context.TODO(), txByte, opts)
```

Any idea how to create type privateKeyGetter which should be passed into Sign()?
https://github.com/gagliardetto/solana-go/blob/main/transaction.go#L452